# main slider not working due to diapo slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

On my website(http://cpshostworks.com/xpertisegulf.com/test12/index.html), the main slider is not working after I put the DIAPO slider. It is caused due to a conflict between 2 jquery files.
Could anyone please help in fixing this issue. I am unable to understand what needs to be done here. I want both the sliders to work (main slider & our partners slider)

I am stuck with this situation for the past one week.

Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

If conflicts occurred between 2 or more jQuery libraries, what I usually do is wrapping `$(document).ready` function like this:

```
 (function ($) {
   $(document).ready(function(){
     //here you can call your plugin function
   });
  })(jQuery);
```

It prevents libraries conflict.
For more information, visit this link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

**EDIT**: Please note that you should do it for every jQuery plugin separately. So if you want to call another plugins function, you should wrap it again in different scope.

**SECOND EDIT** After inspecting your code in console I founded errors. Instead of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
});
```

try with

```
(function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
     });
 })(jQuery);
```

and do it for all following functions calls.

Comment: I have added the above code, but still it does not work. The updated link is http://cpshostworks.com/xpertisegulf.com/test13/index.html

Comment: As I can see you have wrapped it in inverse way. Copy code  I posted and paste your jQuery function bellow comment //here... Also you declared `code`var tpj=jQuery;`code`. That is wrong.